# Is it possible to order posts by two meta values?

Tags: custom-field, sort

Hopefully this is a reasonably straightforward question!

Is it possible to order posts, on the front-end of my WP install, by **two** meta values?

I have a meta key called `genus` and another called `species`. I'd like to sort firstly by `genus` (ASC), then `species` (ASC).

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't do it using a meta query. Check [this example](http://codex.wordpress.org/wpdb#Examples_4), does what you want.

Comment: You can do this! But it is not simple, read this please: http://pluginus.net/wp_query-filter-by-multiple-meta-values-and-order-by-other-meta-values/

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution I can think of is to join the posts meta table with posts table twice. Modifying [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query#Query_based_on_Custom_Field_and_Sorted_by_Value) example a bit you can use this:

```
$querystr = "
SELECT wposts.* 
FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta1, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta2
WHERE wposts.ID = wpostmeta1.post_id
AND wposts.ID = wpostmeta2.post_id
AND wpostmeta1.meta_key = 'genus'
AND wpostmeta2.meta_key = 'species'
AND wposts.post_type = 'post'
ORDER BY wpostmeta1.meta_value ASC,
         wpostmeta2.meta_value ASC
";
```

Comment: +1 Thanks, this was way simpler than the link in the accepted answer.